# HTML tag parsing and write to file with Perl

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I can't grab multiple html tag content from one file.  Here's the last part of my code that could be parsing and printing the text to one file with one row for each file it reads:

```
   my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
   my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new($h);
   $p->parse($text);


   for ($h->header_field_names) {
      my @values = split ',', $h->header($_);
      if (/keywords/i , /description/i , /title/i) {
         $csv1->print ($fh1, \@values);

      #} elsif (/description/i) {
      #   $csv1->print ($fh1, \@values);
      #} elsif (/title/i) {
      #   $csv1->print ($fh1, \@values);


  }
   }
}
```

I can get and write the first tag to a file but nothing more.
Ultimately I'd like to get a CSV or tab delimited row with multiple values.

I made very basic html files that look like this

```
<head><keyword>Test</keyword>
<description>Test2</description>
<title>Test3</title></head>
```

I've tried a few different ways with no luck.

I can always extract content from  but never from  and .   in the HTML file in front of  will cause it to not see the content.  Real life HTML files vs. my made up ones also seem to stump it.

Comment: First, what is the question? Second, please create a [mcve] that highlights whatever problem it is that you're having.

Comment: Focused and kept it short and sweet per above request.

Comment: @tlialin I tried to format correctly the for loop at the end of your post. Please review it because I removed one `}` in the process, which looked like an accident.

Comment: I rolled the question back to revision 4, which was the original question before it started mutating.

Comment: @tlialin please stop making large code changes to the question -- if you have a new question please use the "ask question" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. (`<description>` and `<keyword>` are not valid elements.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::HeadParser;
use HTTP::Headers;

my $text = <<'EOF';
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Foo Bar Baz</title>
  <meta name="description" content="foo">
  <meta name="author" content="bar">
</head>
EOF

my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new($h);
$p->parse($text);

for ($h->header_field_names) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", $_, $h->header($_));
}
```

Output:

```
Title: Foo Bar Baz
X-Meta-Author: bar
X-Meta-Charset: utf-8
X-Meta-Description: foo
```

---

**Update**

If you want to create a CSV file, `use Text::CSV` and change the print loop to something like this:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({eol => $/});
my @fields = ('Title', 'X-Meta-Author', 'X-Meta-Description');
$csv->print(*STDOUT, [map { $h->header($_) } @fields]);
```

Which produces:

```
"Foo Bar Baz",bar,foo
```

I'll leave the part about iterating over multiple input files and printing to a different filehandle up to you.

Comment: OK, invalid elements I can get that.  I see your output and that's great but I only want certain tags like title and meta description and meta author.  I could write to a file from what you've provided and regex that out but I'm at a loss on how to do it all at once.  I also must admit that I can't get the write to file part to work.  I tried:     my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
   my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new($h);
   $p->parse($text);

   for ($h->header_field_names) {
       print ($fh1, "%s: %s\n", $_, $h->header($_));
   }
   
      } with no luck.

Comment: I have no idea what you expect the output format to look like.

Comment: Sure, sorry.  CSV file, one line per input file.  Something like:  Title,Meta-Author,Meta-Description, <link to raw data file> so someone can open in excel easily.

Comment: @tlialin You can't keep expanding the scope of the question indefinitely. If you have a different problem, ask a different question. I've rolled your question back to the most minimal code snippet that actually exhibits the main problem you're asking about.

Comment: @tlialin Also read about [what you should do when someone answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You've asked a bunch of questions without accepting any answers, which some people on SO would consider rude.

Comment: Just accepted your answer.  I'll ask my new question in a different post. Thanks